# Calling Oracle sqlldr using Python

Tags: python, oracle, shell, sql-loader

I am trying to load sqlldr using python so and i am using subprocess.call for that.

```
cmd = 'sqlldr USERID={user}/{password}@Databse_name control={controlfile} data={datafile}'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

the output shows:

sqlldr USERID={user}/{password}@Databse_name control={controlfile} no such directory of file

Can someone help me with this and what do we add after the @ in this?

Comment: Unless you have a really huge dataset and are using direct path loads, you might find that using cx_Oracle's `executemany()` is as fast, and easier.  See the cx_Oracle doc, https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html

Answer (score 0):

Provide the **full path**, not only file names.

Comment: I did provide the fullpath still it shows same error

Comment: This: "no such directory of file" suggests different. Do you have access to all files included into the operation?

Comment: Yes. i do have . Still I'll check once more. thanks

Comment: btw syntax is correct right?

Comment: Seems to be; I don't know Python, though, but - as far as Oracle is concerned - should be OK, e.g. `sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test.ctl data=test.txt` which is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with shell. Make sure u have downloaded instant_client for oracle as well sqlldr.

```
import os
import subprocess

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
control_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'SAMPLE_ITEM_LOAD.ctrl')
data_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sample_item_load.csv')

my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PATH"] = f"{my_env['ORACLE_HOME']}:{my_env['PATH']}"

sql_con = f'{username}/{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_sid}'

sql_ld_command = f'sqlldr {sql_con} CONTROL={control_file} DATA={data_file}'
    sql_ldr_proc = subprocess.Popen(sql_ld_command,shell=True,
                                       env=my_env,
                                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            
    out, err = sql_ldr_proc.communicate()
    retn_code = sql_ldr_proc.wait()
```